# Adding a new drop down menu item in django model field

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a model field that is a foreign key. It shows as a drop down on the form based on the values in the table. I want to add another item in it saying 'Add New' that when selected, should open up a modal form. Could anybody please help on how to achieve this?

**models.py**:

```
class Agent(models.Model):
    agent_phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    agent_desc = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    agency = models.ForeignKey(Agency, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

**forms.py**:

```
class AgentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Agent
        fields = ('agent_phone', 'agency', 'agent_desc')
```

The 'agency' field on the form is populated with rows in the 'Agency' table in a drop down. I want to add another item 'Add new' that should open up a form to add new agency or add a 'Add New' link on the side of drop down that should open up the Add form. Could anybody please advise how to achieve this?